# reactjs not importing css

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, next.js

I am working with nextsjs based project, here in other pages if I load css like this then it works

```
import css from './cssname.css';

<div className={css.myclass}></div>
```

but now I am dealing with a [lightbox component](https://fraina.github.io/react-popupbox/) I need to import css for this, so I this

```
import "react-popupbox/dist/react-popupbox.css"
```

css dosen't work in my code. here is my full code which I copy paste from [docs](https://fraina.github.io/react-popupbox/) first example.

```
import React ,{Component} from 'react';
import { PopupboxManager, PopupboxContainer } from 'react-popupbox';
import "react-popupbox/dist/react-popupbox.css"

class lightbox extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.openPopupbox = this.openPopupbox.bind(this);
    }

    openPopupbox(){
        const content = (
            <div>
              <p>Work like you don't need the money.</p>
              <p>Dance like no one is watching.</p>
              <p>And love like you've never been hurt.</p>
              <span>― Mark Twain</span>
            </div>
          )
          PopupboxManager.open({ content })
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div> 
                <button onClick={this.openPopupbox}>Click me!</button>
                <PopupboxContainer/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default lightbox
```

Comment: Change import to `import './cssname.css';` and `<div className="myclass"></div>`

Comment: @Nithish I follow Docs (https://github.com/fraina/react-popupbox) but css is not working and doing the same way which you suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nextJS doesn't allow you to import CSS file expect on pages/_app.js. Create a pages/_app.js file if not already present. Then, import the CSS file. for more check the doc: [Built-In CSS Support](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support)